# SQLiteException no such column: kevin error in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to delete a single row in my database through this method:

```
    public boolean deleteNote(long row,String name){
        int doneDelete = 0;
        doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE,KEY_ROWID + " = " + row + " and " +  KEY_TITLE + " = " + name, null) ;
        Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
        return doneDelete > 0;
}
```

my table schema is:

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
                KEY_TITLE + "," +
                KEY_CONTENT + "," +
                KEY_TIME + "," +
                " UNIQUE (" + KEY_TITLE +"));";
```

These variables are assigned as:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
public static final String KEY_TIME = "time";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Notes Database";
private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

I use this method when a button is click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "deleting: " + titleStr, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dbHelper.deleteNote(position, titleStr);
            Intent i = new Intent(DisplayNote.this, MainActivity.class);
            dbHelper.close();
        }
```

When the button is clicked, the user goes back to the main activity and the note is removed from the list, but when I press the button I get this error:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: kevin (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Notes WHERE _id = 4 and title = kevin
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.delete(SQLiteDatabase.java:1494)
        at com.kevguev.notesapp.NotesDBAdapter.deleteNote(NotesDBAdapter.java:95)
        at com.kevguev.notesapp.DisplayNote$1.onClick(DisplayNote.java:51)
```

Answer (score 4):

"Kevin" is a **string**.
As such, it must be enclosed in apostrophes (**'**).

So, your instruction should be:

```
doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE,KEY_ROWID + " = " + row + " and " +  KEY_TITLE + " = '" + name + "'", null);
```

Or, better, you could use a **bound parameter**:

```
doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE,KEY_ROWID + " = " + row + " and " +  KEY_TITLE + " = ?", new String[name]);
```

In this case, Android parses the string for you.